# Node package Link issue

Tags: node.js, npm, react-redux

I have been using the node package [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/link) for my project and it worked perfectly fine. But when i exported my project to another computer, Link does not seem to link the supposed paths, even though it runs without any error and it results to have been linked them. When i use `npm start` it cannot find the linked files. It actually still works in the machine that i initially started it as a project. It is still on production and i have not yet built it. Can anyone guide me how to approach this issue?

Edit no.1: Tried switching back to Node 6.0.0 because the machine where it works runs on that version of Node. The issue still persists.

Edit no.2: Unlinked. Tried linking backwards. Error keeps persisting.

Additional information:

- Node version: 8.9.1
- Link version: 0.1.5
- The project is mainly written on React-Redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update and solution: After many trials, errors and some mentoring. The issue was that i had started the project with  `create-react-app`. Therefore i used `npm eject` and so i had access to the files outside /src without the usage of the Link package.